# Solutions to Kepler problem/Motion in central field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

It is clear that particals in a repulsive central field given by a point mass at the origin are moving along hyperbolas, e.g. given by the expression ${x^2 \over a^2} - {y^2 \over b^2} = 1$ (after a change of coordinates). This also applies to three dimensions since the motion takes place in a plane due to conservation of angular momentum.

On the other hand, in three dimensions, the motion satisfies the initial value problem
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}
{d^2X \over dt^2} = C {X \over |X|^3}, \\
X(0) = x, \dot X(0) = v
\end{array}\right.
$$
for some given initial position and velocity $(x,v) \in \mathbb{R}^6$.

Unfortunately, while I can derive the trajectories, I have no idea, what can be said about the speed at which the particle moves at a certain time. In particular, I am interested in the quantitative behavior of $|V| = |\dot X|$ for given $x$ and $v$.

Are there any expansions or explicit expressions for the solution $X$ of the above initial value problem? Or is there any expansion or explicit expression for the absolute velocity $|V|$?

**EDIT**
By conservation of energy we know that
$$
\frac{1}{2}|V|^2 = \frac{1}{2}|v|^2 + C\left(\frac{1}{|x|} - \frac{1}{|X|}\right).
$$
On the other hand, the behaviour of $\frac{1}{|X|}$ is well understood according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem#Solution_of_the_Kepler_problem
$$
\frac{1}{r} = -\frac{km}{L^{2}} \left[ 1 + e \cos \left( \theta - \theta_{0}\right) \right].
$$
Actually, I don't quite understand how $\theta$ can be replaced by a time dependent expression and how the constants depend on the initial data $x$ and $v$...

Answer (score 0):

You have rightly answered your own question in EDIT.

Putting $k m/ L^2 = 1/p $  where p is semi-latus rectum, the last equation becomes

$$ \frac{p}{r} =  \left[ 1 + e \cos \left( \theta - \theta_{0}\right) \right] $$

in which $ \theta $ is the polar coordinate for classical polar conic equation.If $ \theta_0 $ is is non-zero, the conic is rotated so that major axis would not be along x- or y- axis.

You would notice that  certain values of L,m k and total energy E decide eccentricity e. It will be found that high energy orbits force the orbit along non-returning hyperbolas.

Notice also that this same Newtonian formulation can result in hyperbolas, no need to have a separate repulsive differential equation. e =2 for hyperbolic orbits are sketched in:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit

EDIT1:

In order to change to independent time variable from $\theta$ independent variable,

$$ u''+ u = -1/p, \theta^{'} = L u^2 $$

the latter part expresses conservation of angular momentum.

Comment: I don't know, how this answers my question. It's still mysterious, how the constants depend on $x$ and $v$ and we still only have a representation depending on $\theta$, while I'm interested in the evolution in time.

Comment: Actually the set of derivatives of $ x , v $ and the dynamic relations involve the constants.

Comment: It seems to me like the derivation of this solution in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem#Solution_of_the_Kepler_problem is nonsense (it is asserted that $\omega$ is a conserved quantity). But the derivation on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit looks good. However, I still don't understand, how you get an expression in the time variable from this.

Comment: @thomas: Please see carefully it says that $ m \omega r^2 = L $, the angular momentum is conserved. There is no neat closed form expression for $ r = f(t) $ existing, may be possible in elliptic integrals,let me check.. The ellipse $ r- \theta $ relation is in closed form of course. $ r'' + \mu/r^2 - h^2 /r^3 = 0 $ is the radial ODE to be solved for $ r-time $ relation.

Comment: Oh, I see. You are right. I understood the $\equiv$-sign as "equals constantly", but they seem to use it in the sense "defined as" (which I usually denote by $:=$). So, possibly there is no expansion for $r=|X|$ in terms of $t$. But my question was actually targeted at some expansion of $|V|$ in terms of $t$, possibly only an estimate. I had some hope that at least that would be possible.

Comment: You can get solutions for $V, r,\theta$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: You think I can get solutions in terms of $t$? How?